# cross domain iframe access

Tags: iframe, cross-domain

I have a packaged Visualforce page ( hosted on dev1 for example) which is trying to access another VF page hosted on client's org (org myclient, for example) by using apex:iframe, the iframe is rendered as blank area, I googled it and found this

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_forcecom_cruc_setup_pages.htm

Then I made another experiment by developing another VF page on dev1(so there is cross-domain issue to load this page), upon uploading, this page sends AJAX request to client's org, and I got error 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load MYCLIENT VF PAGE. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin PACKAGED PAGE is therefore not allowed access.'

So what is the 'best practice' to handle cross-domain iframe access in SalesForce? I believe this requirement is not uncommon. Thanks very much.

Comment: I also need to know this! Did you find an answer?